Markers on Google maps in flutter gets a larger touch target on Android compared to iOS
When using Google maps in flutter with markers. The markers will have a larger touch target in Android, compared to iOS.
android touch target
Usually on iOS the touch target is the marker it self, while Android will add padding around the touch target, to make it easier to be clickable. As shown in the picture above, the porblem occurs if I want to make iOS markers easier to hit and creates an image with padding. Then the android markers will have too much padding, causing many misclicks for markers close to each other.
One sultion would be to use different icons for Android and iOS, but I am wondering if there is any better solution out there, like turning off the extra padding given from Android. Also if the markers er close to each other and not overlapping, how would one avoid the misclicks?

Here you can find more information.
This is an old issue reported.
link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24865

I have just been playing with this. I was supplying image files at
higher resolution, @2x and @3x for iOS and the equivalent for Android.
These files are just being ignored and only the base resolution image
is being used. iOS then automatically scales the images for higher
resolution screens, but Android doesn't do this automatic scaling and
just displays the icon at 1x. This is why the icons appear larger on
iOS than on Android.

One hack to deal with it:
BitmapDescriptor get deliveryIcon {
   bool isIOS = Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS;
   if (isIOS)
      return BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset('assets/icons/orange_pin.png');
   else
      return BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset('assets/icons/3.0x/orange_pin.png');
}

A better implementation is using Uint8List:
Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(String path, int width) async {
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
  ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(), targetWidth: width);
  ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png)).buffer.asUint8List();
}

Here you have more info:

How to change the icon size of Google Maps marker in Flutter?


This is a different issue and not related to what I am asking. This issue is talking about the markers being larger on iOS than on Android. My issue is not related to the size of the marker, but the touch target. Meaning if you have a circle on the map, it might be equally large on iOS and Android, but the clicks are registered on Android even if I click further away from the circle itself. While in iOS they are only registered when I click on the circle.
